# VBA. Picture, decoded from Base64 string, needs to be inserted into Excel sheet

Tags: image, vba, excel, vbscript, base64

I need to store encoded PNG image in a vbs script, then launch Excel, decode stored in VBS base64 image, and insert this image into Excel. In [this article](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_Base64/) I found decoding solution. Finally, I got decoded string with image bytes in it.

But how I can insert into Excel obtained bytes as image object?

As I comprehend, `xlApp.activesheet.Pictures.Insert(strImagePath)` works with files only.

Comment: Why don't you store decoded PNG image and import it to Excel?

Comment: Some circumstances make me to keep all code in sole file.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't insert pictures in Excel via memory. GDI API would be a choice, however, wrapping it into VBA is HUGE work. Why don't you save memory PNG to temp file and load it?

Comment: I thought about this idea, will try.